# Configuration System Failed to Initialize

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, authentication

I'm currently creating a Login form and have this code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
try
{
    using (OdbcConnection connect = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connect.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT username, password FROM receptionist", connect);
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (username_login.Text == username && password_login.Text == password)
        {
            this.Hide();
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid User", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }
        else 
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid User", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        connect.Close();
    }
}
catch (OdbcException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

But whenever I try to type in the username and password there is an error called "*Configuration system failed to initialize*". What kind of problem is this, and how could I solve this?

Comment: See [Configuration system failed to initialize exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443235/net-3-5-configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-exception)

Comment: Just another scenario - If you are looking for ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[""], make sure that the <appSettings> is present in the config. Otherwise you will get this exception

Comment: This can also happen if you have 2 locations for appsettings

Comment: This can also happen if a reserved character is used, for example an ampersand in a password element.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

Make sure that your config file (web.config if web, or app.config if windows) in your project starts as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" 
                      type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >

            <section name="YourProjectName.Properties.Settings" 
                     type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                     requirePermission="false" />

        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Note that inside the `configuration` element, the first child must be the `configSections` element.

In the `name` property on `section` element, make sure you replace ***`YourProjectName`*** with your actual project's name.

It happened to me that I created a webservice in a class library project, then I copied (overwriting) the config file (in order to bring the endpoints configuration) to my windows app and I started to have the same problem. I had inadvertently removed `configSections`.

Comment: "inside the 'configuration' element, the first child must be the 'configSections' element" << this was the crucial point for me. Thanks.

Comment: Just another scenario - If you are looking for ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[""], make sure that the <appSettings> is present in the config. Otherwise you will get this exception

Comment: It fixed my problem where `configSections` element existed but located later part of the app.config. I can't help asking why this error happened. I thought XML elements don't need to be ordered.

Comment: It's 2014 and it still is helpful! I was adding a webservice to application and messed something with this config file. Still application compiled perfectly and gave this error only when running. I would never guess what was the problem.

Comment: Before you do all this make sure the config file has no illegal chracter or xdtTransfoms attributes/

Comment: This is correct. The configSections should be the first child node under, configuration element.

Comment: The way Microsoft implemented this app.config is retarded!!! The least they could do is throw a better error message!

Comment: This worked just right! I had included the new section but hadnt referenced the section's type, name of it in the "configSections" tag. Thank you! :)

Comment: check out my answer below

Comment: I had put my `<appSettings></appSettings>` section first, instead of `configSections`. I made 'configSections` first, inside `<configuration>` and THEN put `<appSettings>` and it worked fine. THANK YOU! Would never have thought that order was important!

Comment: 2021 and still happens > VS 2019, C# Service project, the <startup> tag stood in front of <configSections> and messed up the App.config...

Answer (score 130):

Delete old configuration files from **c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\appname** and **c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\appname** and then try to restart your application.

Comment: Thanks, working. But I still don't understand what is problem?

Comment: under the local folder user.config file was blank. After deleting local folder app start working

Comment: Thanks it worked. But what could be the reason for this error.

Comment: I *think* this can happen when you install/uninstall/reinstall/debug an application. At least that seems like what happened to me.

Comment: My file was filled with low-values (0x00). I copied a working one in and then it was fine

Comment: This can also be affected when modifying user settings as this is the default location for its' storage.

Comment: My config file in this location was corrupted during a power outage event - the config file which is normally XML was filled with NUL bytes

Comment: I changed the Namespace in a Project in a multi-project VB.NET Solution and this seems to be what screwed things up. This fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: We had an issue where the hard disk was full and it probably coudnt update the correct config file. It then created new config files in the folders of this answer. Deleting them fixed the problem.

Comment: This solved it for me. This happened to me when I was testing/running my app and it froze and I had to do a hard shut off of my computer.

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes the Error occurs because a windows create a duplicate in the

> C:\Users\App Data\Local\"You App Name"...

Just delete this folder and done. try it.

Comment: THANK YOU. I was unable to fix my issue with settings file strings not being "picked up" by my application. I cleaned out the config files, regenerated the .suo file, deleted all existing .settings files and was still unable to load from any new settings file, but did not receive any errors on build. This nightmare has finally come to an end.

Answer (score 15):

If you've added your own custom configuration sections to your `App.Config`, make sure you have defined the section in the `<configSections>` element.  I added the my config XML but forgot to declare the configuration section up top - which caused the exception "Configuration system failed to initialize" for me.

Comment: Also - if you have a section declared up top and the name in the section below has a typo, you will get this error.  If you look at the InnerException of the thrown exception, it will tell you which section is the problem.

Comment: That innerException that @shindigo mentioned will also tell you WHERE the offending file is.  In my project it's nowhere near the User's App Data, but rather at `[project_path]\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\MVVM Playground.dll.config`.  Deleting it made the error of an improperly defined section go away, but then the application couldn't find any data.  I had to manually copy my `App.config` into that file.

Comment: I additionally discovered that `App.config` can be set to always "Copy if newer" when running the debugger:  Click on the file in the Solution Explorer and additional properties appear that aren't available when simply viewing the file.  Change property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

Answer (score 9):

After a long search I realised, this exception has an inner exception that tells you exactly what is wrong with your config file

Comment: I was trying to comment-uncomment different sections of my app.config and on exception didn't even look on inner exception. And after seeing this answer I found what was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem with an MSTest class: [Marlon Grech in his article](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/problem-configuration-system-failed-to-initialize/) says "the  element has to be defined as the first element in the App.config."

So make sure that  is the first element in under the  element. I had put AppSettings first.

Comment: ohh .. my bad: you indeed did but I didn't notice ;-) Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 5):

If you have User scoped settings you may also have a user.config file somewhere in the `[Userfolder]\AppData\Local\[ProjectName]` folder.

If you later remove the User scoped settings the user.config will not automatically be removed, and it's presence may cause the same error message. Deleting the folder did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered but I had exactly the same problem in my unit tests. I was tearing my hair out - adding an appSettings section, and then declaring the configuration section as per the answer. Finally found out that I had already declared an appSettings section further up my config file. Both sections pointed to my external settings file "appSettings.config" but the first appSettings element using the attribute **file** whilst the other used the attribute **configSource**. I know the question was about the connectionStrings. Sure enough, this happens if the appSettings element is the connectionStrings element being duplicated with different attributes.

Hopefully, this can provide someone else with the solution before they go down the path I did which leads to wasting an hour or two. *sigh* oh the life of us developers. We waste more hours some days debugging than we spend developing!

Comment: Bingo. Had `appSettings` and `applicationSettings` both.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xyz" value="123" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

I started to get this problem after uninstalling Oracle Client Drivers and it removed my **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\machine.config**!

Copying it from another computer resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Easy solution for **.Net Core** WinForms / WPF / .Net Standard Class Library projects

**step 1:** Install `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` by Nuget Manager

**step 2:** Add a new `App.Config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Bodrum" value="Yalikavak" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**step3:** Get the value

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Bodrum");
// value is Yalikavak
```

If you are calling it from a `Class Library` then add the `App.Config` file on your Main Project.

Comment: Yes, and see the end of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482184/795690 if you want this to also work with a test project.

Answer (score 1):

Wow it took me forever to figure out this one. For some reason changing the attribute `[assembly: AssemblyCompany("CompanyName")]` at `AssemblyInfo.cs` made this error disappear. I was referencing a project that had a different value for the attribute `[assembly: AssemblyCompany("CompanyName")]`. I maked sure both projects had the same attribute value and it worked great!

Comment: Is this a bug?  One can hardly be expected to make your company name match a third party project you happen to reference.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with me I solved my problem by removing verion="v3.5" from  App.config.

**Before**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>

  <startup>

 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
 </startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v3.5" />//Remove this
</configuration>
```

**Solution**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  </configuration>
```

Here is how to use version on

[MSDN Support Runtime Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the below code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"
                  type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >

      <section name="YourProjectName.Properties.Settings"
               type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
               requirePermission="false" />

    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SPUserName" value="TestUser" />
    <add key="SPPassword" value="UserPWD" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only solution was to add the reference to the `System.Configuration` in my Test project as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that if you add things like connection strings into the app.config, that if you add items outside of the defined config sections, that it will not immediately complain, but when you try and access it, that you may then get the above errors.

Collapse all major sections and make sure there are no items outside the defined ones.  Obvious, when you have actually spotted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda dumb, but for me I fixed it by doing a get latest from source control on my code. I think there was some new configuration element that was added by someone else, and I needed to overwrite my configuration files. OP shows the error I had gotten, which wasn't really pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem, But accidentally i written the 
without writting the ,the previous one should go inside this tags. thus the 'Configuration System Failed to Initialize' error was arising.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I have two configsections in the app.config file. After deleting the one hiding in the code lines, the app works fine.

So for someone has the same issue, check if you have duplicate configsections first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with an Azure WebJob - I had to remove the following after upgrading to the latest 4.6.1.

```
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, within my .edmx file I had run the 'Update Model From Database' command. This command added an unnecessary connection string to my app.config file. I deleted that connection string and all was good again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the .config file as utf-8 if you have some "special" characters in there. That was the issue in my case of a console application.

Answer (score 0):

As ***@Flash Gordon*** mentioned in his comment, you will need to define any custom tag (as a section) in your **App.config** file, under `<configSections>`. For example, you're working on a test automation project with SpecFlow & adding `<specFlow>` tag, then a simplest version of App.config will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this and it was because I had a `<configuration>` element nested inside of a `<configuration>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Visual studio and even the whole PC.
I cleaned the project, rebuild, and deleted bin file.

Nothing helped until i changed the configuration from x64 to x86.
It worked on x86 but when i changed it back it also worked!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the solutions above trying to figure out why one of my unit tests were failing to pick up the configuration from an app.config file that is perfect.

I had 2 references to the same assembly like so:

[image: duplicate reference]

[image: project file before and after]

Removing the (duplicate) reference in yellow fixed it for me.

I hope this works for someone else, it drove me nuts for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom section, you need to mention that under configSections right below configurations tag.

Please check your transform files, make sure you remove the unnecessary tags.only the section that are going to vary needs to be there in transform files. dont mention config section in the transform files if not needed. this would also cause the problem.

if you have any syntax error in machine.config, then also this error is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting

```
'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll
```

If you have windows check the slashes `/` I was working with a project from a guy working in linux, so he had inverted them.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from .net to .netcore.  App.config remained in my project, but I had migrated my settings to Settings.settings.  The fix for me was removing the .config file from the Debug/Release folders, renaming/removing App.config and re-compiling/re-running the project.