# Configuration system failed to initialize in log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, connection-string, log4net-configuration

I am getting this exception "Configuration system failed to initialize" while reading connection string from app_config in window application

```
string con = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
```

on this line after entering following lines

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs. if i remove this line from  Assemblyinfo.cs then there is no exception i am adding this assembly for logging purpose

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure but if you are using VSTO for MS Office Add-In Development than below post might help you.

[Why is log4net not recognized in configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106682/why-is-log4net-not-recognized-in-configuration-file)

You need to add log4net also in the section block

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/> 
</configSections>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a .NET problem, not a log4net problem.  Your app.config file isn't being loaded.  See [Configuration System Failed to Initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize) for a good answer to the real problem.