# linq to sql from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am trying to figure out why this connection of Linq to Sql will not work.

I have the dbml and DataContext set up, and everything works fine.  If I call this function from within the same project everything works fine.  It is all set to public , and I want to call this function from another project. When I do so I get the following exception:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.

not much more detail in that exception except this :

> "Configuration system failed to initialize"

the error is being thrown on this line , which is the firstline of the function

```
  using (EngageDataContext db = new EngageDataContext())
        {
```

like I said , I know that everything is set up for the dbml , connection string and datacontext properly because it works when called from within the same project.  Anyone have any idea whats going on?

Comment: It might not be the same root cause, but the first Google hit for me was: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6472696/328193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this happens if the app.config file isn't formatted correctly.  This would be a starting point.  I've run into this when I didn't have a connection string within the connectionString section.

Comment: for some reason using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[..]  worked fine for a SqlDataConnection with my invalid app.config , but the dbml wasn't gonna have it