# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException when starting WCG service

Tags: .net, wcf

A bit panicked at the moment. I am trying to install a software update for a customer and somehow my WCF service fails and gives me an error message I haven't seen before. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          2014-01-03 16:03:36
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SERVER.NM.LOCAL
Description:
Application: MyApp.Web.Trading.WindowsServiceHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Stack:
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetConfigurationSection(System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(System.Configuration.ContextInformation, System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupService(System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(System.Type, System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(System.Type, System.Uri[])
   at MyApp.Web.Trading.ServiceImplementations.Wcf.Start()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be due to a bad .config file. Can you please check it and look for bad constructed xml or open tags?

Comment: Yes, I had a duplicate line in a .config file. Thanks. Will remove the question now, if that's okay. Oh, turns out I can't :)

Comment: Worked for me, uncommented some things and had an extra --> left behind. Thanks

Comment: The only dupe line was a comment! What?! Well... just be careful about this one also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize

Comment: Check that (1) The configuration file is a well formed xml i.e. every element has a closing element, and there are no extra commenting characters (2) Any extra sections, other than *appSettings*, are defined in the *configSections*.