# 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll, System.Configure already included

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, connection-string, app-config

I have a Windows Form application in VS 2013 and I'm trying to establish a database connection. Every time I run the program, however, I receive the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in         
System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize
```

Here's what my files look like:

### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
....

namespace ProgramName
{
    static class FakeNameB
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

### Form1.cs

```
using System;
....

namespace ProgramName
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            string CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[<nameInApp.config>].ConnectionString.ToString();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

### App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ProgramName.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections> 
    <configurationStrings>
        <add name = <name> connectionString = "Data Source=<dataSource>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add> 
    </configurationStrings>
</configuration>
```

None of the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize) seemed to help, and I was not able to reference System.Configuration.dll like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536715/get-connection-string-from-app-config) suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a "by the way" - if you _did_ have a missing include, the program wouldn't have compiled at all

Comment: The build didn't fail, so it would appear that the inclusion is not missing. Do you think I need to run clean solution instead?

Comment: I see you've fixed it, but maybe next time it will be easier (and safer) to edit the config file using VS' visual designer.

Answer (score 4):

The fix to this particular issue could be found in the comments of the accepted answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize), and was resolved by moving the configSections tag to be the first child of  and moving the startup tag to be the last section included.

Answer (score 3):

In your app.config, it should be `<connectionStrings>` not `<configurationStrings>`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="[name]" connectionString="[string]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```