# Configuration error c# App config

Tags: c#

I am writing a console application for moving integration file from Shared drive to the linux server using C#.New application works fine and doing its job, recently I have decided to use configuration file save attributes like filepath.

Since I have started using the configuration file I am getting an error "Configuration system failed to initialize" with no further detail. Below is the text from my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<Appsettings>

<Add key="UserName" value="my username" />
<Add key="HostName" value="Ip Add" />
<Add key="Password" value="MyPassword" />
<Add key="SshHostKeyFingerprint" value=" code" />
<Add key="sourcepath" value="file path" />
<Add key="destinationpath" value="file path" />
<Add key="MagentoDestinationpath" value="file path" />
<Add key="filestomove" value="*.csv" />
<Add key="Logfilepath" value="file path" />


</Appsettings>
</configuration>
```

I have commented out all code apart from below line to trouble shoot

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WinSCP;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
Using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
namespace Magentogiftcard
{
 class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        string Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UserName");
        Console.WriteLine("Host");  

    }

    }

  }
```

But still getting this issue. I will appriciate any help.

regards
Jahangir Khizer

Comment: Your Config file is not a correct format. please refer the link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize

Comment: Hi Ash, I am new to C#, I have got this format  from microsoft link below.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/815786 . It is used exactly the same format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appSettings` element and it's child elements are **case sensitive** so `<Appsettings>` and `<Add…` are causing the error.

Change them to

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="destinationpath" value="file path" />
```

Intellisense illustrates this:

[image]

Comment: By the way, I think the `using` directive is case-sensitive too (for `System.Configuration`)

Comment: Thanks for replying back to me. I have change the case but still getting the same issue

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
          <configuration>
          <appsettings>
          <add key="example" value="example" />
         <add key="example" value="example" />
         <add key="example" value="example" />
        <add key="example" value="example" />
        <add key="example" value="example" />
       <add key="example" value="example" />
       <add key="example" value="example" />
       <add key="example" value="*.csv" />
      <add key="example" value="example" />
      </appsettings>  </configuration>

Comment: Okay got it appsettings has to be appSettings. I am not sure what is the insentive behind getting on capital 'S' in the middle of a word. Thanks my issue is resolved