# Using app.config in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have problem. I need to write a program in .Net Core(C#) which use app.config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="custom" type="ConfigurationSample.CustomConfigurationSection, ConfigurationSample"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sampleDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sampleApplication" value="Configuration Sample"/>
  </appSettings>
  <custom>
    <customConfigurations>
      <add key="customSample" name="Mickey Mouse" age="83"/>
    </customConfigurations>
  </custom>
</configuration>
```

and I write:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sampleDatabase"].ConnectionString;
Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

// read appSettings configuration
string appSettingValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sampleApplication"];
Console.WriteLine(appSettingValue);
```

and it is example from the internet so I thought would work, but I am getting exceptions:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Error Initializing the configuration system.'
Inner Exception
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationHost' from assembly 'CoreCompat.System.Configuration, Version=4.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'get_bundled_machine_config' has no implementation (no RVA).
```

I downloaded via NuGet - Install-Package CoreCompat.System.Configuration -Version 4.2.3-r4 -Pre and still don't work. Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: I think for .net core you will use json files for configuration. Look up on that.

Comment: In .NET Core you use appsettings.json, not app.config.

Comment: but I said about .Net Core and not ASP.Net core

Comment: "It is example from the internet so I thought would work" - biggest misconception ever.

Comment: Microsoft has also released a NuGet package that allows you to use classic config files with .NET Core https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Comment: This might be relevant to future visitors. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572248/897326

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. You can use [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) with **any** .NET Core app, not only with ASP.NET Core app.
   Look into sample provided in the link, that shows how to read configs in the console app.
2. In most cases, the JSON source (read as `.json` file) is the most suitable config source.

   > Note: don't be confused when someone says that config file should be `appsettings.json`. You can use any file name, that is suitable for you and file location may be different - there are no specific rules.

   But, as the real world is complicated, there are a lot of different configuration providers:

   - File formats (INI, JSON, and XML)
   - Command-line arguments
   - Environment variables

   and so on. You even could use/write a custom provider.
3. Actually, `app.config` configuration file was an XML file. So you can read settings from it using XML configuration provider ([source on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/tree/master/src/Config.Xml), [nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml/)). But keep in mind, it will be used only as a configuration source - any logic how your app behaves should be implemented by you. Configuration Provider will not change 'settings' and set policies for your apps, but only read data from the file.

Answer (score 97):

It is possible to use your usual `System.Configuration` even in .NET Core 2.0 on Linux. Try this test example:

1. Created a .NET Standard 2.0 Library (say `MyLib.dll`)
2. Added the NuGet package `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` v4.4.0. This is needed since this package isn't covered by the meta-package `NetStandard.Library` v2.0.0 (I hope that changes)
3. All your C# classes derived from `ConfigurationSection` or `ConfigurationElement` go into `MyLib.dll`. For example `MyClass.cs` derives from `ConfigurationSection` and `MyAccount.cs` derives from `ConfigurationElement`. Implementation details are out of scope here but [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20custom%20configuration%20section%20tutorial).
4. Create a .NET Core 2.0 app (e.g. a console app, `MyApp.dll`). .NET Core apps end with `.dll` rather than `.exe` in Framework.
5. Create an `app.config` in `MyApp` with your custom configuration sections. This should obviously match your class designs in #3 above. For example:

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="myCustomConfig" type="MyNamespace.MyClass, MyLib" />
  </configSections>
  <myCustomConfig>
    <myAccount id="007" />
  </myCustomConfig>
</configuration>
```

That's it - you'll find that the app.config is parsed properly within `MyApp` and your existing code within `MyLib` works just fine. Don't forget to run `dotnet restore` if you switch platforms from Windows (dev) to Linux (test).

Also, the location of app.config at runtime is different than what was in .net framework, instead of "projectName.exe.config". It is now "projectName.dll.config" in .net core.

**Additional workaround for test projects**

If you're finding that your `App.config` is not working in your test projects, you might need this snippet in your test project's `.csproj` (e.g. just before the ending `</Project>`). It basically copies `App.config` into your output folder as `testhost.dll.config` so `dotnet test` picks it up.

```xml
  <!-- START: This is a buildtime work around for https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22101 -->
  <Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="App.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.dll.config" />
  </Target>
  <!-- END: This is a buildtime work around for https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22101 -->
```

Comment: This should be the right answer, migration from .NET Framework to .NET core will be quick and easier if this trivial thing can be bypassed

Comment: Thank you for the test project workaround! Might be worth adding, if the test project is separate from the main project, you can copy `App.config` from the main project, to avoid having a duplicate copy in the test project. Just copy from `..\MainProject\App.config` in the above, instead of from `App.config`.

Comment: This is a hack fix and it bothers me that so many people find hack fixes like this acceptable.  I am not looking to maintain custom Configuration Managers.

Answer (score 20):

I have a .Net Core 3.1 MSTest project with similar issue. This post provided clues to fix it.

Breaking this down to a simple answer for .Net core 3.1:

- add/ensure nuget package: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to project
- add your app.config(xml) to project.

If it is a MSTest project:

- rename file in project to testhost.dll.config

  OR
- Use post-build command provided by DeepSpace101

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to copy manually testhost.dll.config to the bin folder

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to import further dependencies, so settled on the following:

```cs
class Main
{
    private static readonly NameValueCollection AppSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appSettings = new MemoryConfigurationSource
        {
            InitialData = AppSettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => AppSettings[key]),
        };
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Add(appSettings)
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Just mapping ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to MemoryConfigurationSource.