# web.config in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: web-config, asp.net-core-2.0

I just started learning ASP.NET Core 2 MVC application.

After taking a new project, I don't see any web.config file in solution explorer.

Any help?

Sorry if this a foolish question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using app.config in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034007/using-app-config-in-net-core)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not just `Asp.Net Core 2.x` no longer uses `web.config`, even the `Asp.Net Core` no longer uses it.

The configuration now is part of the application startup procedure, in `Startup.cs`. And there is an application setting file called `appsettings.json` where you can put all your configuration values there.

You can read setting values like this:

#### appsettings.json

```js
{
    "Recaptcha": {
        "SiteKey": "xxxx-xxxx",
        "SecretKey": "xxxx-xxxx"
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       ...

       // Configure Google Recaptcha
       // reading values from appsettings.json
       services.AddRecaptcha(new RecaptchaOptions
       {
           SiteKey = this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Recaptcha:SiteKey"),
           SecretKey = this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Recaptcha:SecretKey")
       });
    }
}
```

Also in `.Net Core` projects, there is `.csproj` file. You can right click a project and click `Edit <project>.csproj`.

`web.config` will be generated after you publish your web projects.