# Server Explorer vs SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 2.2 +EF app: do I need to bother with Server Explorer, or can I just create my databases and use them with SQL Server Object Explorer?

Also, for some reason my `web.config` file does not appear in my solution and I was thinking that this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I need to bother with Server Explorer, or can I just create my databases and use them with SQL Server Object Explorer?

Yes, you could see your database just in SQL Server Object Explorer.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

> Also, for some reason my web.config file does not appear in my solution and I was thinking that this is the problem

Asp.net core do not use web.config any more.

When you publish your project, it does create a web.config. If you publish to a folder profile, you will see it there, or if you publish to IIS/Azure you will also see the file using File Explorer or Azure Console.

Refer to [web.config in ASP.NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343113/web-config-in-asp-net-core-2)