# App.config with a console application in C# on Mac

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config

I'm writing a console application in C# in Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac, and I added an `App.config` file, I can't seem to access any of the values. How do I do this correctly? This may be related to the target framework being .Net core?

- I added the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` NuGet package.
- I added the App config file according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-app-config-file?view=vs-2019)

The contents of the app config are very simple:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="key" value="value" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The program definition is also very simple:

```C#
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Config");
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]);
        foreach (var str in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        foreach (var str in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End Config");
    }
}
```

When I run the project from the play button, I expect to see `value` twice in the output at least. Instead I get:

> Config
>
> data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
>
> End Config
>
> Press any key to continue...

In the `bin/debug` folder there's only a `ProjectName.dll` and no `ProjectName.config`. What exactly could the problem be? Might it be related to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e72ea75c-8caf-4311-b929-27431c650c74/app-config-key-not-working)?

Comment: the normal config in a .NET Core app is a json file, as far as I understand. Normally appSettings.json is the default. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2 . So I expect you an put your extra value in there and read it quite easily within the app. Having said that, it looks like you _could_ use a .config XML file if you wanted, with a couple of extra steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034007/using-app-config-in-net-core

Comment: Try checking AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile for where its reading/looking for that file