# asp.net core config vs console config project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have DLL's added from the project and it is dependent on the App.config,

It will work fine when I use the Console project because the config can be read and structure is something like this:

[image]

But if I will try to add the DLL's and App.config on asp.net core project then looks like the problem is it is not reading anymore the App.config and gives me some error when I ran it. here the structure for asp.net core project:

[image]

And for the content of App.config is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="Helper" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection" />
    <section name="Message" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection" />
  </configSections>

  <Helper>
    <add key="IsQueue" value="N" />
    <add key="QueueType" value="Y" />
  <Helper>

  <Message>
    <add key="BrokerName" value="Y"/>
  </Message>

</configuration>
```

Any suggestion/comments why it doesn't work for asp.net core project. TIA

Comment: asp.net core uses (by default) appsettings.json.

Comment: is there a way to change the default reading from appsettings.json to App.config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034007/using-app-config-in-net-core