# Where is my C# console application 'app.config' file

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config

Why there is no `app.config` file in my c# console application by default. I have been watching many tutorials on entityframework, and in all of them, there is `app.config` by default.
Why i dont have it in my console app?
[image]
I need that file so i can add configure string to it

Comment: Are you using .NET Core (or .NET 5 or 6) or are you using .NET Framework?

Comment: just to be sure, is it a `.Net Framework` or a `.Net Core` project? you can check on project properties (right click your project > properties). the thing is `.Net Framework` uses `app.config` while the `.Net Core` uses `appsettings.json`.

Comment: [How to: Add an application configuration file to a C# project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-app-config-file?view=vs-2022)

Comment: `app.config` isn't used in .NET Core onwards (without [some effort to add it back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482184/1320845)), and EF Core won't use it either. I suspect the tutorials you've been watching relate to .NET Framework and Entity Framework 6.

Comment: .NET 5/6 are .NET *Core* 5 and 6. .NET Core no longer uses `app.config` files. You'll find an `appsettings.json` file instead. You're probably looking at an outdated tutorial. Instead of trying to add `app.config` for no benefit, find a better tutorial. The new config system is completely different, far easier to use and actually allows mixing multiple config sources, including env variables, files, databases, remote services. `appsettings.json` is just a common name for a JSON config file. You can easily add your own.

Comment: .net core: are you looking for appsettings.json ? This is not added by default to keep things simple as apps might not need it. You can add just like any other file in your application.

Comment: If you really want to learn about the old Entity Framework, you need to create a .NET Framework Console application, not .NET/.NET Core console. The old EF is in maintenance mode though, all new features are added to Entity Framework Core.

Comment: FYI Entity Framework Core (EF Core), the Entity Framework "version" for .NET Core, is a ground up re-implementation of Entity Framework, and such is fundamentally different in some ways. I recommend you either look at tutorials that teach EF Core *or* (as a learning exercise) switch to using .NET Framework

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. The thing is that i have been using .Net 5 and watched outdated tutorials. I will watch tutorials on EntityFrameworkCore now.

Answer (score 1):

The newer .NET Cores (5 & 6) no longer use a `app.config` file.

You should use an `appsettings.json` file.

From the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/configuration/appsettings.json):

> All of the application's settings are contained in a file named
> appsettings.json. Any changes to the appsettings.json file will
> require restarting the "Microsoft IIS Administration" service to take
> effect.
>
> The appsettings.json file is located at: %SystemDrive%\Program
> Files\IIS
> Administration<version>\Microsoft.IIS.Administration\config\appsettings.json

But not just for web apps, but any Console app also follows the same config methodology. The above link has examples to cover most cases.