# Unrecognized element in connection string

Tags: c#

Can't find what is wrong with my connection string:

I get this exception:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element. (D:\C#\learncsharp\Data access\AsyncSQL\AsyncSQL\bin\Debug\AsyncSQL.exe.Config line 2)

This is my code:

```
string connectionString = null;
string MovieDBContext = null;

try
{
    MovieDBContext = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MovieDBContext"].ConnectionString;
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProgrammingInCSharpConnection"].ConnectionString;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine( e.ToString() );
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MovieDBContext"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ProgrammingInCSharpConnection" 
             connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ProgrammingInCSharp;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

What is wrong? And how to get details which element is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuration System Failed to Initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize)

Comment: post your whole config file

Comment: this is whole config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the section in the **`<configSections>`** element.Change your config as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections />
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="MovieDBContext"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        />
         <add name="ProgrammingInCSharpConnection" 
              providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
              connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ProgrammingInCSharp;"
        />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Got the same exception and have warning : `Warning  The element 'configSections' has invalid child element 'connectionStrings'. List of possible elements expected: 'section, sectionGroup'.`

Comment: Problem fixed after removing  <configSections> or just place them in the same lavel :  
`

 <configSections>
 </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="MovieDBContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        />
   <add name="ProgrammingInCSharpConnection"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ProgrammingInCSharp;"
        />

 </connectionStrings>

`