# Config file structure

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

I got mixed with `app.config` file.

I had config that [failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248857/unrecognized-element-in-connection-string) to get connectionStrings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
         <add name="ProgrammingInCSharpConnection"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ProgrammingInCSharp;" />
    </connectionStrings>
   </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Problem was solved after placing `<connectionStrings>` outside of `<connectionStrings>` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections />
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       <add name="ProgrammingInCSharpConnection"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ProgrammingInCSharp;" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But I found many samples with pattern below

```
<configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
       ...
    </connectionStrings>
</configSections>
```

It might work in some cases?
What is logic of configuration file in general and what kind of information might be located in each section?

Comment: For the record: you are talking about the `app.config` file while you have the `web.config` and `asp.net` tag. Which of the two you are talking about?

Comment: Since you moved on to another question already, can you please respond to the answers here?

Comment: This is for app.config. But in general it would be nice to know about web.config

Answer (score 0):

The `configSections` node contains configuration section **per namespace declarations**, but is not usually used for connection strings, unless they are namespace - specific.

> But I found many samples with pattern below

The patterns you found could never work since `<connectionStrings>` is not allowed to be nested **directly** under `<configSections>`.
This could be achieved, by stating a connection string variable under the `<section>` itself, and if the server code targets them via a specific namespace.

An example:

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="section1" type="System.MyNameSpace" />
   </configSections>
   <section1 connString="...conn.." />
</configuration>
```

In the example above the namespace `System.MyNameSpace` will now have a variable (field) called `connString`, so it can target it in code behind.

For conclusion, if your connection strings are not per namespace, the `<connectionStrings>` element should be nested directly under the `<configuration>` node and no where else.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to have a valid `app.config` file and yet having a `connectionStrings` in your `configSections` node.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350.aspx), this is the list of allowed elements:

- `section`
- `sectionGroup`
- `add`
- `clear`

`connectionStrings` isn't in the list and I don't expect an application to find the connection strings in that place.