# XamlParse Exception in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xamlparseexception

I get the XamlParse Exception in this code:

```
</ContentPresenter.Content>
    <ContentPresenter.Effect>
        <l:BrightContrastEffect
            Brightness="{Binding ElementName=bSlider, Path=Value}"
            Contrast="{Binding ElementName=cSlider, Path=Value}"/>
        </ContentPresenter.Effect>
</ContentPresenter>
```

This used to run error free initially. However, after I added this code:

```
<connectionstrings>
<add connectionstring="Data Source=UVSS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CPASUVSS;Integrated Security=True;" name="ConnectionString"/>
</connectionstrings>
```

into the app.config file; exception is thrown. I wanted to understand what is causing it and how to solve it.

Comment: You mean that, if you remove that xaml from your .xaml file the exception is **not** thrown?

Comment: No, if I remove the <Connectionstrings> in the app.config file; the exception is not thrown

Comment: did you bind the `Value` for `bSlider` or `cSlider` to something that tries to read from database?

Comment: Not a database but from an external file

Comment: Look at the inner exception.

Comment: Inner Exception points to the file where `bSlider` and `cSlider` are binded. Its throwing `Configuration system failed to initialize` exception

Comment: You can also try the answer to the [.NET 3.5 - Configuration system failed to initialize exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443235/net-3-5-configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-exception) question.

Comment: I have tried those answers. They didn't work