# ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, xmlserializer

I am getting an exception I have no clue how to debug. It is thrown on the following line:

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Universe));
```

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException has been thrown
Error Initializing the configuration system.

What is the configuration system, where is it getting initialized and what does it have to do with the XmlSerializer?

The full exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section <runtime> (/MyPath/Projects/Stars/Stars/Stars.Desktop/bin/Debug/net471/Stars.Desktop.app/Contents/MonoBundle/Stars.Desktop.exe.config line 3)
  at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.ThrowException (System.String text, System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigInfo.cs:77 
  at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadContent (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Configuration.Configuration config, System.Boolean overrideAllowed, System.Boolean root) [0x0011f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/SectionGroupInfo.cs:330 
  at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadRootData (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Configuration.Configuration config, System.Boolean overrideAllowed) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/SectionGroupInfo.cs:273 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.ReadConfigFile (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.String fileName) [0x000ce] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:572 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Load () [0x00043] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:532 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Init (System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigSystem system, System.String configPath, System.Configuration.Configuration parent) [0x0005d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:138 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:96 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/InternalConfigurationFactory.cs:41 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationInternal (System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, System.Reflection.Assembly calling_assembly, System.String exePath) [0x000ea] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:119 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:49 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:52 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:61 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:159 
  at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/misc/PrivilegedConfigurationManager.cs:24 
  at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/DiagnosticsConfiguration.cs:171 
  at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize () [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/DiagnosticsConfiguration.cs:209 
  at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_SwitchSettings () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/DiagnosticsConfiguration.cs:29 
  at System.Diagnostics.Switch.InitializeConfigSettings () [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Switch.cs:272 
  at System.Diagnostics.Switch.InitializeWithStatus () [0x00046] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Switch.cs:211 
  at System.Diagnostics.Switch.get_SwitchSetting () [0x0000a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Switch.cs:144 
  at System.Diagnostics.BooleanSwitch.get_Enabled () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/diagnostics/BooleanSwitch.cs:39 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly (System.Type type, System.String defaultNamespace, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerImplementation& contract) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compilation.cs:164 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.String defaultNamespace) [0x0007e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs:198 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs:177 
  at Stars.SaveManager.SaveLoader.SaveUniverse (Stars.Game.Universe universe) [0x0005d] in /MypPath/Projects/Stars/Stars/Stars/SaveManager/SaveLoader.cs:39
```

Comment: I think source of exception is at another part of your code like web.config

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443235/net-3-5-configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-exception

Comment: It looks like your code is serializing xml and giving an error when it is being saved.  It is either due to the xml have bad format or the xml contains illegal xml characters.  I would put a break point into SaveLoader.cs and get the string xml and then put the string into a online xml verifier to find error.  You can verify xml in VS using menu : Project : Add New Item : XML.  Then paste the xml string into the view.  Error will show up in Error list just like compiler errors.

Comment: The error occurs before any actual serialization. All I am passing in is the class type, and I am trying to write it, not read it. There is no XML file at this point.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to application configurations. I am not sure how to define them correctly, especially since I don't even want to use them at all. I found a config file inside the monobundle of the dev build, but that is autogenerated. I tried various of the suggested solutions, but nothing seems to fix it, and the error message seems to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in app.config file. There is a problem with the section ***runtime***. Be sure it is declared in  and has valid structure and values.

Here the Inner exception message gives the hint

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section <runtime>
```